# android DownloadManager use in Activity vs. Service (or IntentService)

Tags: android, android-download-manager

What is the most common used case scenario or the best practice of using a DownloadManager? I mean implementing it in Activity vs. Service (or IntentService). I've looked at the Android's documentation and read the [DownloadManager's reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) but couldn't find anything that answers why and when I should prefer to use a DownloadManager in an Actiivity or respectively in a Service (or IntentService).

What are the pros. and cons. of using one way over the other?

Comment: You do not "implement a DownloadManager". `DownloadManager` is a system service. You *use* `DownloadManager` to download files on the user's behalf.

Answer (score 0):

> The download manager is a system service that handles long-running HTTP downloads... The download manager will conduct the download in the background...

You can use it from every place where you can call the `getSystemService()`. The service itself is in charge of running a download task for you.

Answer (score 0):

[An activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is a single, focused thing that the user can do.... - everything what going on there - you can see it 
 
[Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) you can call from Activity to do task in bacground. However if you want to download somethig from internet better will be IntentSrvice (use AsyncTask) or AsyncTask.

But:

> The Android [DownloadManager introduced](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/) in Android 2.3. (API 9) is a
>   system service which allows to handle long-running HTTP downloads in
>   the background and notify the triggering application via a broadcast
>   receiver once the download is finished.

DownloadManager is 'special' system service. I posted link to description and also tutorial.